# Convert Word to Images in Python

Tags: python, python-3.x, image, ms-word

I have an example word document. How can I convert the word document to images, where each image represent each page in the word document using Python? Any idea?

Comment: Lol, I just finished my solution for this before it was closed. Re-ask the question and ping me to answer.

Comment: @MatthewGaiser- Can you help me answer this Sir? https://stackoverflow.com/questions/59916371/convert-text-to-image-in-python

Answer (score 1):

I think you could take each character and translate it into a color code, based on the character code, and its index in the string could determine its position in the image after.

```py
height, width = size = 500, 500  # makes it easier to unpack them individually, or together.

msg = 'Hello world foo bar egg spam ' * 100_000  # just to give a good sized string.
codes = [chr(letter) for letter in msg]  # convert each to a number.

''' The list called codes above just has a
single number for each letter, and it wouldn't
let you make an RGB code from that, unless you
were to use it as a hex code. You could do an
operation with the index of that letter in the
message, and then keep the number within the bounds
of 0 to 16^6 - 1 (ffffff). 

What I might do is:
hex( (index(letter) * chr(letter)) % (16^6 - 1) )
but you could do what you'd like. 

I hope this was helpful.'''
```

Comment: Answer the wrong question